# List-formatted text file into list

Tags: python, list, file, text, formatted

First of all: apologies if this question has been already asked. I have tried finding it on the site for quite some time now.

Essentially the problem is very simple: I have a text file that is already formatted like a python list:
`["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]`

I'm simply looking for the most simple way to parse this into a variable, ie.

```
print(testVariableOne)
>["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]

print(testVariableOne[0])
>["test1"]
```

I was thinking maybe of using regex to split each element, but this seems a bit convoluted.

Apologies for the (almost definitely) repeated question.

Comment: Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ast.literal_eval you can safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display.

something like this :

```
import ast
file_content='["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]'
file_content=ast.literal_eval(file_content)
```

and your output will be a list .